# How do I prove this algebraically?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

The locations of the real numbers $m, n$, and $p$ are shown on the number line in Figure . Which of the following statements is NOT always true?

a) $mn>−n$

b) $n−m<p$

c) $−1<m+n<1$

d) $np<p$

e) NONE

edited figure

$$-1<m<0<n<1<p<2$$

We have the following inequalities

1. $0<n<1$
2. $-1<m<0$
3. $1<p<2$

If (2) is multiplied by $n$ because it is positive, $-n<mn<0$ remains, which is always true.

If (2) is multiplied by $-1$, $0<-m<1$ remains if we add (1) remains $0<n-m<2$, which is always true.

I can't move forward with the one with $p$ to try the alternatives.

Comment: Rather than your "*figure*"... just write $-1<m<0<n<1<p<2$

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) True. As you showed.

(b) False. Take $n = 0.8, p = 1.1,$ and $m = -0.9$. Then $1.7 = n-m \not < p = 1.1$.

(c) True. $ 0 < n < 1$ and $-1 < m < 0$ so $0 < m + 1 < 1$. Then $0 < n + m + 1 < 2$ so $-1 < n+m < 1$.

(d) True. $p > 1$ and $0< n < 1$ so $0 < np < p$, as desired.

Comment: Note to wally: Your error with b) is that while you correctly deduce $n-m<2$, that that doesn't help you. Knowing that both $n-m$ and $p$ are smaller than 2 doesn't say anything which one of them is smaller.